# В чём разница: лесник (от лес) и лесник (от лесной)

Tags: значение-слов

В словаре Тихонова у слова *лесник* зафиксировано два значения:

> 1. Лес/ник от слова **лес**.
> 2. Лес/н/ик от слова **лесной**.

Если с первым значением всё более-менее понятно (хотя там ещё предстоит разбираться в тонкостях значений и разнице с *лесничим*), то что же значит слово *лесник* во втором значении совершенно неясно.

Буду благодарен за разъяснения и, если возможно, пример предложения во втором значении.

Answer (score 1):

Схема 1. Лес — лес/н/ой — лес/н/ик

ЛЕСНИК,  м. **Лесной** сторож; работник **лесного** хозяйства.

Схема 2. Лес —  лес/ник

ЛЕСНИК, лицо, которое по роду своей деятельности связано с **лесом**.

**Обе формальные схемы продуктивны,** поэтому указаны в словаре. С другой стороны, при разборе чаще используется схема 1, а схема 2 применяется там, где она является единственно возможной, например: работа — работник, охота — охотник, двор — дворник.

Семантика слова ***лесник*** не зависит от выбора формальной схемы образования и определяется **по толковому словарю.**